# Can't install subversion on Mountain Lion OSX

Tags: macos, svn, installation

I downloaded the subversion installer in the "Community Binaries" at collabnet:
http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion#tab-3. When I try to install it, I go through Introduction, Read Me, and License. When I get to Destination Select, "Install for all users of this computer" is greyed out. I can not proceed during this point. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mountain Lion does have Subversion version 1.6.18 available from Apple. However, it's a bit convoluted to get it:

- Download Xcode from the Mac OS X App Store (Free program)
- Select the Menu item Xcode->Preferences...
- Select the "Downloads" section.
- Choose *Command Line Tools* and click on the *Install* button.

After that, the Subversion command line client will be available. The `svnserve` server is also included. Unfortunately, the `mod_dav.so` and `mod_dav_svn.so` files needed for running Subversion server via Apache https are no longer included. I think they might be included in Mac OS X Server, but that's a $20 purchase.

Hope this helps. It's not version 1.7.x, but it's much easier to get working than the old *community binary* version which I don't believe works in Mountain Lion (and is also version 1.6.18)

Comment: Don't forget the path is "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/"

Comment: Actually, on mine it's in /usr/bin/svn. Maybe it's a hold over from Lion/Snow Leopard, but it has the same sha1 as the one in /Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin.

Comment: How do you set the Path in Coda if I Xcode is an app not a folder?

Comment: @iMohammad Applications on the Macintosh are just special folders with the extension `.app`. If the standard open dialog box won't let you open the application, you can open a Finder Window, Control-click on the application, select "Show Folder Contents, then find the file, and drag it into the Open dialog box.

Comment: @iMohammad Another trick, if you are comfortable with Unix command line is to create a directory like `/usr/share/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, and then symbolically link all of the executables in the enclosed _hidden_ `/bin` directory to `/usr/share/bin`. You can then go to `/usr/local/bin` when you need to open an executable in the open dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need Xcode, you can download the Developer Command Line Tools from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action directly, saving yourself a tonne of disk space and time...

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently it's not been updated](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=440239) is the message on open.Collab.net...

> Date   2011-12-20 04:44:22 PST
>   Message  The community volunteer who provides the binary on our site has not updated it for Lion or SVN 1.7. All of the Mac packaging tools, like MacPorts and HomeBrew have updated and you can get it there. There is also a listing of places to get them here: http://subversion.ap​ache.org/packages.ht​ml#osx